# Modify names only for some columns

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, names

I have a dataset like **original**.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4)
period <- c(1,1,2,2,1,2,3,1,3)
iso_1 <- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1)
iso_2 <- c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1)
iso_3 <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1)

original <- data.frame(id, period, iso_1, iso_2, iso_3)
```

I like to modify the column names that have a pattern "iso_name" and add "_exp", so it looks like "iso_name_exp". The **new** dataset looks as follows:

```
iso_1_exp <- c(1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1)
iso_2_exp <- c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1)
iso_3_exp <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1)
new <- data.frame(id, period, iso_1_exp, iso_2_exp, iso_3_exp)
```

I did try the following line:

```
n <- ncol(original)
colnames(original)[,3:n] <- paste0(colnames(original)[,3:n],"_exp")
```

However it didn't make the trick.

Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
original %>% rename_with(~paste0(., '_exp'), starts_with('iso'))

#  id period iso_1_exp iso_2_exp iso_3_exp
#1  1      1         1         1         1
#2  1      1         0         1         0
#3  1      2         0         1         1
#4  2      2         0         0         0
#5  3      1         1         0         0
#6  3      2         1         1         1
#7  3      3         0         0         0
#8  4      1         1         1         0
#9  4      3         1         1         1
```

Base R :

```
cols <- grep('^iso', names(original))
names(original)[cols] <- paste0(names(original)[cols], '_exp')
```

Comment: Super thanks Ronak. Dplyr way works, but not the Base R one.

Comment: Oops..sorry you are right. Corrected the answer @vog

Answer (score 3):

In base R you could modify by index:

```
colnames(original)[3:5] <-  paste(colnames(original)[3:5], "exp", sep = "_")
```

Or in case of multiple columns up to last(n) you could use `ncol()`:

```
colnames(original)[3:ncol(original)] <-  paste(colnames(original)[3:ncol(original)], "exp", sep = "_")
original
```

Output:

```
 id period iso_1_exp iso_2_exp iso_3_exp
1  1      1         1         1         1
2  1      1         0         1         0
3  1      2         0         1         1
4  2      2         0         0         0
5  3      1         1         0         0
6  3      2         1         1         1
7  3      3         0         0         0
8  4      1         1         1         0
9  4      3         1         1         1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
original %>% 
  rename_with(~str_c(., '_exp'), starts_with('iso'))
```

Comment: Akrun good to see you. Could you please assist here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67254566/unable-to-perform-recoding-in-r-for-factor-variables/67255255?noredirect=1#comment118880060_67255255>

Comment: @TarJae your code is working fine for me with the example