# Unable to perform recoding in R for factor variables

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am trying to recode some variables to factors to perform some basic visualizations. However, I encounter following error:

Error:

```
Error: `.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not a `data.frame` object.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
`.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not a `data.frame` object.
Backtrace:
 1. `%>%`(...)
 2. dplyr::mutate_at(...)
 3. dplyr:::manip_at(...)
 4. dplyr:::tbl_at_syms(.tbl, .vars, .include_group_vars = .include_group_vars)
 5. dplyr:::tbl_at_vars(tbl, vars, .include_group_vars = .include_group_vars)
 6. dplyr:::bad_args(...)
 7. dplyr:::glubort(fmt_args(args), ..., .envir = .envir)
```

My code:

```
d <- d %>% mutate_at(
  .vars = vars(contains("Dem_edu")),
  .funs = recode, 
  "- PhD/Doctorate" = "PHD", 
  "- Up to 12 years of school" = "12 years",
  "- Up to 9 years of school" = "9 years", 
  "- Up to 6 years of school" = "6 years",
  "- College degree" = "Col_degree",
  "- None" = "None",
  "- Some College or equivalent" = "Col",
  "1" = "1")
```

Not sure what am I doing incorrectly.

Result of `dput(head(d))`

```
> dput(head(d))
structure(list(StartDate = structure(c(1585219216, 1585219822, 
1585220572, 1585221981, 1585222622, 1585222239), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), EndDate = structure(c(1585220433, 1585220592, 1585221557, 
1585222697, 1585223366, 1585223396), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Status = c("IP Address", "IP Address", "IP Address", 
"IP Address", "IP Address", "IP Address"), Progress = c(100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100), `Duration (in seconds)` = c(1217, 770, 
984, 716, 743, 1156), Finished = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE), RecordedDate = structure(c(1585220434, 1585220593, 1585221558, 
1585222698, 1585223367, 1585223397), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), ResponseId = c("R_2uHCOahB4DrY5Mb", "R_sBeXDjmvUERjTqh", 
"R_3Dvlhb30AxXS5VX", "R_O6Fpln9BAtyuftv", "R_ZDXNVSta8CbZs89", 
"R_Uhfke7fjjClqv85"), DistributionChannel = c("anonymous", "anonymous", 
"anonymous", "anonymous", "anonymous", "anonymous"), UserLanguage = c("DA", 
"DA", "DA", "SCU", "DA", "FI"), Consent = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), Dem_age = c(57, 54, 52, 27, 25, 38), Dem_gender = c("Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female"), Dem_edu = c("- Up to 12 years of school", 
"- Some College, short continuing education or equivalent", "- Some College, short continuing education or equivalent", 
"- College degree, bachelor, master", "- College degree, bachelor, master", 
"- PhD/Doctorate"), Dem_edu_mom = c("- Up to 12 years of school", 
"- Some College or equivalent", "- Some College or equivalent", 
"- PhD/Doctorate", "- Up to 12 years of school", "- College degree"
), Dem_employment = c("Retired", "Full time employed", "Full time employed", 
"Student", "Student", "Full time employed"), Country = c("Denmark", 
"Denmark", "Denmark", "Canada", "Denmark", "Finland"), Dem_Expat = c("yes", 
"yes", "yes", "no", "yes", "yes"), Dem_state = c(NA, "København", 
"Skanderborg", "Ontario", "Københavns Kommune", NA), Dem_maritalstatus = c("Married/cohabiting", 
"Divorced/widowed", "Married/cohabiting", "Divorced/widowed", 
"Married/cohabiting", "Divorced/widowed"), Dem_dependents = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Dem_riskgroup = c("Yes", "Not sure", NA, "Yes", 
"No", "Yes"), Dem_islolation = c("Life carries on with minor changes", 
"Life carries on with minor changes", "Isolated", "Isolated", 
"Life carries on with minor changes", "Life carries on with minor changes"
), Dem_isolation_adults = c(1, NA, 1, 1, 3, 1), Dem_isolation_kids = c(1, 
NA, 0, 0, 0, 0), AD_gain = c(NA, NA, NA, "· If Program A is adopted, 200 people will be saved.", 
"· If Program A is adopted, 200 people will be saved.", NA), 
    AD_loss = c("· If Program C is adopted 400 people will die.", 
    "· If Program C is adopted 400 people will die.", "· If Program D is adopted there is 1/3 probability that nobody will die, and 2/3 probability that 600 people will die.", 
    NA, NA, NA), AD_check = c("Not sure", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
    "No", NA), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_1 = c("Very often", "Almost never", 
    "Fairly often", "Sometimes", "Never", NA), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_2 = c("Sometimes", 
    "Never", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Very often", NA), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_3 = c("Fairly often", 
    "Sometimes", "Fairly often", "Sometimes", "Almost never", 
    "Sometimes"), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_4 = c("Sometimes", "Very often", 
    "Very often", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", NA), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_5 = c("Sometimes", 
    "Fairly often", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", NA
    ), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_6 = c("Sometimes", "Almost never", "Sometimes", 
    "Sometimes", "Fairly often", NA), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_7 = c("Sometimes", 
    "Fairly often", "Fairly often", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", 
    "Almost never"), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_8 = c("Sometimes", "Fairly often", 
    "Almost never", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", NA), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_9 = c("Very often", 
    "Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Almost never", "Almost never"
    ), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_10 = c("Fairly often", "Never", "Sometimes", 
    "Sometimes", "Almost never", NA), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_11 = c("Fairly often", 
    "Almost never", "Sometimes", "Sometimes", "Fairly often", 
    NA), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_12 = c("Fairly often", "Almost never", 
    "Almost never", "Sometimes", "Never", NA), Scale_PSS10_UCLA_13 = c("Very often", 
    "Never", "Fairly often", "Sometimes", "Fairly often", NA), 
    OECD_people_1 = c(5, 7, 7, 0, 5, 3), OECD_people_2 = c(5, 
    9, 9, NA, 7, NA), OECD_insititutions_1 = c(5, 7, 8, NA, 8, 
    NA), OECD_insititutions_2 = c(5, 8, 9, NA, 7, NA), OECD_insititutions_3 = c(5, 
    8, 9, NA, 6, NA), OECD_insititutions_4 = c(1, 6, 8, NA, 7, 
    NA), OECD_insititutions_5 = c(NA, 6, 9, NA, 6, NA), OECD_insititutions_6 = c(5, 
    7, 8, NA, 6, NA), Corona_concerns_1 = c("Agree", "Slightly disagree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly disagree"), Corona_concerns_2 = c("Agree", "Disagree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", NA), Corona_concerns_3 = c("Agree", 
    "Disagree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly disagree"), Corona_concerns_4 = c("Strongly agree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly agree", NA), Corona_concerns_5 = c("Strongly agree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", 
    NA), Trust_countrymeasure = c("Too much", "8", "4", "Appropriate", 
    "7", "6"), Compliance_1 = c("Agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Strongly agree", NA), Compliance_2 = c("Agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", 
    NA), Compliance_3 = c("Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree"), Compliance_4 = c("Agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Disagree"), Compliance_5 = c("Agree", 
    "Agree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", 
    NA), Compliance_6 = c("Slightly agree", "Slightly agree", 
    "Disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", NA), BFF_15_1 = c("Agree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Agree", NA), BFF_15_2 = c("Agree", "Slightly agree", "Agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Agree", NA), BFF_15_3 = c("Slightly agree", 
    "Slightly disagree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly disagree", NA), BFF_15_4 = c("Slightly disagree", 
    "Slightly disagree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly agree", NA), BFF_15_5 = c("Agree", "Slightly disagree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Agree", NA), BFF_15_6 = c("Slightly agree", 
    "Agree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", 
    NA), BFF_15_7 = c("Strongly agree", "Slightly disagree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", NA), BFF_15_8 = c("Strongly agree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly agree", 
    NA), BFF_15_9 = c("Slightly agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly agree", NA), BFF_15_10 = c("Slightly agree", "Slightly disagree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Disagree", NA), BFF_15_11 = c("Slightly agree", 
    "Disagree", "Slightly disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", 
    NA), BFF_15_12 = c("Slightly agree", "Slightly disagree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", NA), BFF_15_13 = c("Slightly disagree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", 
    NA), BFF_15_14 = c("Slightly disagree", "Slightly agree", 
    "Slightly disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Agree", NA), BFF_15_15 = c("Slightly agree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly agree", NA), Expl_Distress_1 = c("Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Disagree", "Slightly disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", 
    NA), Expl_Distress_2 = c("Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Does not apply to my current situation", NA), Expl_Distress_3 = c("Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Does not apply to my current situation", "Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Does not apply to my current situation", 
    NA), Expl_Distress_4 = c("Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Slightly agree", "Agree", "Strongly disagree", "Agree", 
    NA), Expl_Distress_5 = c("Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Does not apply to my current situation", "Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Does not apply to my current situation", 
    NA), Expl_Distress_6 = c("Strongly agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly agree", NA), Expl_Distress_7 = c("Agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", NA), Expl_Distress_8 = c("Slightly agree", 
    "Disagree", "Does not apply to my current situation", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly agree", NA), Expl_Distress_9 = c("Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Does not apply to my current situation", "Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Does not apply to my current situation", 
    NA), Expl_Distress_10 = c("Strongly agree", "Agree", "Strongly agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", NA), Expl_Distress_11 = c("Strongly agree", 
    "Disagree", "Does not apply to my current situation", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Strongly disagree", NA), Expl_Distress_12 = c("Strongly agree", 
    "Disagree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", 
    NA), Expl_Distress_13 = c("Strongly agree", "Slightly disagree", 
    "Slightly disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", 
    NA), Expl_Distress_14 = c("Strongly agree", "Disagree", "Slightly disagree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Disagree", NA), Expl_Distress_15 = c("Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Disagree", "Slightly disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Does not apply to my current situation", 
    NA), Expl_Distress_16 = c("Strongly agree", "Slightly disagree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", NA), Expl_Distress_17 = c("Agree", 
    "Disagree", "Does not apply to my current situation", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Strongly disagree", NA), Expl_Distress_18 = c("Strongly agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Agree", NA), Expl_Distress_19 = c("Strongly agree", "Slightly agree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Agree", NA), Expl_Distress_20 = c("Strongly agree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly agree", 
    NA), Expl_Distress_21 = c("Strongly agree", "Disagree", "Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Disagree", NA), Expl_Distress_22 = c("Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Does not apply to my current situation", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", NA), Expl_Distress_23 = c("Strongly agree", 
    "Disagree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly agree", 
    NA), Expl_Distress_24 = c("Strongly agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", NA), Expl_Distress_txt = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, "Please exclude - test", NA, NA), SPS_1 = c("Agree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", 
    NA), SPS_2 = c("Slightly disagree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Disagree", NA), SPS_3 = c("Slightly disagree", "Agree", 
    "Slightly disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", 
    NA), SPS_4 = c("Slightly disagree", "Agree", "Slightly agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", NA), SPS_5 = c("Agree", 
    "Agree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", 
    NA), SPS_6 = c("Disagree", "Strongly agree", "Slightly agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", NA), SPS_7 = c("Agree", 
    "Agree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Agree", 
    NA), SPS_8 = c("Disagree", "Slightly agree", "Agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly disagree", NA), SPS_9 = c("Slightly agree", "Agree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", 
    NA), SPS_10 = c(NA, "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Agree", NA), Expl_Coping_1 = c("Agree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", NA), Expl_Coping_2 = c("Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly disagree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Agree", NA), Expl_Coping_3 = c("Agree", "Slightly agree", 
    "Strongly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", 
    NA), Expl_Coping_4 = c("Strongly agree", "Slightly disagree", 
    "Disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", NA), 
    Expl_Coping_5 = c("Strongly disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", NA), Expl_Coping_6 = c("Strongly disagree", 
    "Agree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", 
    NA), Expl_Coping_7 = c("Agree", "Agree", "Slightly disagree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", NA), Expl_Coping_8 = c("Agree", 
    "Disagree", "Slightly disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Agree", 
    NA), Expl_Coping_9 = c("Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly agree", NA), Expl_Coping_10 = c("Slightly disagree", 
    "Slightly disagree", "Slightly disagree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Strongly disagree", NA), Expl_Coping_11 = c("Agree", "Agree", 
    "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", 
    NA), Expl_Coping_12 = c("Agree", "Agree", "Strongly agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", NA), Expl_Coping_13 = c("Strongly disagree", 
    "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", 
    NA), Expl_Coping_14 = c("Agree", "Agree", "Agree", "Strongly disagree", 
    "Slightly agree", NA), Expl_Coping_15 = c("Slightly disagree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", 
    NA), Expl_Coping_16 = c("Agree", "Agree", "Strongly agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", NA), Expl_coping_txt = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, "Please exclude - testing", NA, NA), Expl_media_1 = c("Strongly agree", 
    "Disagree", "Slightly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Agree", 
    NA), Expl_media_2 = c("Strongly agree", "Disagree", "Slightly disagree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Strongly disagree", NA), Expl_media_3 = c("Strongly agree", 
    "Disagree", "Disagree", "Strongly disagree", "Agree", NA), 
    Expl_media_4 = c("Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Strongly agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Disagree", NA), Expl_media_5 = c("Strongly disagree", 
    "Disagree", "Strongly agree", "Strongly disagree", "Slightly disagree", 
    NA), Expl_media_6 = c("Strongly disagree", "Agree", "Agree", 
    "Strongly disagree", "Slightly agree", NA), Final_open = c(NA, 
    NA, "Har altid levet med mild angst og lavt selvværd. Denne situation forværrer angsten.", 
    "Please exclude - testing", NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=English_India.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] expss_0.10.7    multicon_1.6    foreach_1.5.1   abind_1.4-5     psych_2.1.3    
 [6] forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.5     purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.4.0    
[11] tidyr_1.1.3     tibble_3.1.0    ggplot2_3.3.3   tidyverse_1.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6         lubridate_1.7.10   mvtnorm_1.1-1      lattice_0.20-41   
 [5] digest_0.6.27      assertthat_0.2.1   utf8_1.2.1         R6_2.5.0          
 [9] cellranger_1.1.0   backports_1.2.1    reprex_2.0.0       httr_1.4.2        
[13] pillar_1.6.0       rlang_0.4.10       readxl_1.3.1       rstudioapi_0.13   
[17] data.table_1.14.0  checkmate_2.0.0    labeling_0.4.2     foreign_0.8-81    
[21] htmlwidgets_1.5.3  munsell_0.5.0      broom_0.7.5        xfun_0.22         
[25] compiler_4.0.5     modelr_0.1.8       pkgconfig_2.0.3    mnormt_2.0.2      
[29] tmvnsim_1.0-2      htmltools_0.5.1.1  sciplot_1.2-0      tidyselect_1.1.0  
[33] htmlTable_2.1.0    matrixStats_0.58.0 codetools_0.2-18   fansi_0.4.2       
[37] crayon_1.4.1       dbplyr_2.1.0       withr_2.4.1        grid_4.0.5        
[41] nlme_3.1-152       jsonlite_1.7.2     gtable_0.3.0       lifecycle_1.0.0   
[45] DBI_1.1.1          magrittr_2.0.1     scales_1.1.1       cli_2.4.0         
[49] stringi_1.5.3      farver_2.1.0       fs_1.5.0           xml2_1.3.2        
[53] ellipsis_0.3.1     generics_0.1.0     vctrs_0.3.6        iterators_1.0.13  
[57] tools_4.0.5        glue_1.4.2         hms_1.0.0          parallel_4.0.5    
[61] yaml_2.2.1         colorspace_2.0-0   rvest_1.0.0        knitr_1.31        
[65] haven_2.3.1
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your data so that others can see the problem and be sure that they have fixed it. Use `dput(head(d))` and paste the result into the original question.

Comment: @AndrewChisholm, yes I made the necessary edits.

Comment: Thank you - when I run this, I do not see an error.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce your problem. R version 4.0.2  dplyr_1.0.5 macOS Catalina 10.15.7. Try restarting your R session and loading only `dplyr`.

Comment: @AndrewChisholm, that's strange, I still get the same error.

Comment: @IanCampbell, sorry, it didn't work even after restarting.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the relevant sections of the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Also, be noted that I am using R-version `4.0.5`. I'm a bit uncertain if it is due to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all try dplyr::mutate...

Anyway:
Use `across` rather then `mutate_at` ->
Scoped verbs (_if, _at, _all) have been superseded by the use of across() in an existing verb

This code is explicitly on your Dem_edu columns and it should work now

```
df %>% 
  select(contains("Dem_edu")) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Dem_edu"), as.factor),
         across(starts_with("Dem_edu"), ~recode(., "- PhD/Doctorate" = "PHD", 
                                   "- Up to 12 years of school" = "12 years",
                                   "- Up to 9 years of school" = "9 years", 
                                   "- Up to 6 years of school" = "6 years",
                                   "- College degree" = "Col_degree",
                                   "- None" = "None",
                                   "- Some College or equivalent" = "Col",
                                   "1" = "1"))
  )
```

Output:

```
  Dem_edu                                                  Dem_edu_mom
  <fct>                                                    <fct>      
1 12 years                                                 12 years   
2 - Some College, short continuing education or equivalent Col        
3 - Some College, short continuing education or equivalent Col        
4 - College degree, bachelor, master                       PHD        
5 - College degree, bachelor, master                       12 years   
6 PHD                                                      Col_degree
```

Comment: after running your suggestion I get the following:
```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
x 'recode': all recodings should be formula but: "PHD"
i Input `..2` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.```

Comment: This is strange. Have you tried `dplyr::mutate(across...`. Please see my update with my output after applying the same code. Have you loaded `library(tidyverse)`?

Comment: yes, I tried out your `dplyr::mutate` suggestion at first, this solved the issue for other recodings, but your code explicitly for `Dem_edu` still throws me the above error.

Comment: Have you loaded `library(plyr)`

Comment: If it s a `factor` you could use `fct_recode` from `forcats`

Comment: @RanjiRaj It is working fine for me with your dput example.

Comment: @TarJae, `plyr` solved the problem thanks for the hack! however, my other basic data analysis throws me errors. Simple operations like, `d %>% group_by(Country) %>% summarize(n()) %>% print(n=1000)` It used to work before, I searched other posts it says that you must detach it using `detach(package:plyr)` and I tried it it works but the old issue still persists.

Comment: @akrun, Yes I'm aware of the `forcats` implementation, but trying to understand the former behaviour why it happens.

Comment: @RanjiRaj it could be based on many reasons.  1) your R version/package is not uptodate. 2) there may be some other packages loaded in your environment, that masks the `recode` function..